# Remove past years from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "Year" select box from which I need to remove all options with a value < 2014

I do not have access to the html for this form, but it looks like this:

```
<select name="954_23125_3_42202_YEAR" id="954_23125_3_42202_YEAR" title="Year">
    <option value="0">Year</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014" selected="selected">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I am attempting to use:

```
function read() {
    $("#954_23125_3_42202_YEAR option").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value < '2014') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

I seem to be having trouble getting the value from what I think should be the selected option (*edit - selected by jQuery, not the selected option); console is only showing a return of `undefined`

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/N8pYX/

Comment: Since selected year is 2014, and condition is "value < 2014", then no wonder it is not being deleted :).

Comment: *"I seem to be having trouble getting the value from what I think should be the selected option;"* I don't see you getting the value of the selected option? Or are you saying that you are having troubles when the loop reaches the supposedly selected option? How do you log the value? Please provide more information.

Comment: As shown by j08691, your code seems to work as expected. If you don't provide more information about the problem you are experiencing, there is nothing we can do to help you. As it stands, you *don't have* have a problem.

Comment: @frikozoid - Perhaps I wasn't clear, i'm not trying to remove 2014, having trouble differentiated between "Selected" as in by the user and "Selected" as in the element jQuery is targetting

Comment: @Felix Kling - Apologies for the ambiguity. I've edited my op to reflect that I meant selected by jQuery. I'm not so much concerned with the value of the selected option, just the value of the option jQuery has selected. As for logging the value I had console.log(value)

Comment: I recognize that this seems to work in jsfiddle, just not in context. The problem I'm having can't be explained any more clearly, the value returned by $(this).val() always seems to be undefined. Perhaps it's environmental? I appreciate everyones insight, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: That could only mean that `this` doesn't refer to the element you think it does (i.e. to an `option` element). Is this really the exact code you are using? The code, as it is, is correct.

Comment: This really is the exact code I'm using; see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69x83/

Comment: It seems as though you forgot to include the jQuery library from the left-hand panel. Looks like the reason your code is failing is because you are defining the `read()` function but not calling it. http://jsfiddle.net/69x83/2/